# reduceRegions for multiple images at once?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to get statistics for multiple images at once using reduceRegions() function?

My case: I need to get statistics from multiple images (elev, slope, tree cover loss) for multiple region (grid)

```js
// Add reducer output to the Features in the collection.
var gridmeans = elev.reduceRegions({
  collection: grid,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
});

print(gridmeans);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: gridmeans,
  description:'biggridmeans',
  fileFormat: 'csv'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get statistics for multiple locations from multiple images, you can combine images together using [ee.Image.addBands()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageaddbands) as shown in the following example:

```js
// Define images.
var elev = ee.Image("NOAA/NGDC/ETOPO1");
print('elev', elev);

var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elev.select('bedrock')).rename('bedrock_slope');
print('slope', slope);

// Stack the bands of multiple images together.
var stacked_image = elev.addBands(slope);
print('stacked_image', stacked_image);

// Define a feature collection (grid features).
var grid_1 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-105.29, 39.98, -105.28, 39.99);
var grid_2 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-105.28, 39.98, -105.27, 39.99);
var grid_3 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-105.27, 39.98, -105.26, 39.99);
var grid = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(grid_1, {'name': 'Grid 1'}),
  ee.Feature(grid_2, {'name': 'Grid 2'}),
  ee.Feature(grid_3, {'name': 'Grid 3'})
]);
Map.addLayer(grid, {}, 'grid');

// Add reducer output to the Features in the collection.
var gridmeans = stacked_image.reduceRegions({
  collection: grid,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
});
print('gridmeans', gridmeans);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: gridmeans,
  description:'biggridmeans',
  fileFormat: 'csv'
});
```